# How to get megahertz frequency with a 555?

Tags: 555, high-frequency, astable

I need to produce a 1.7 MHz signal. Up to around 200 kHz the 555 IC and my simple astable circuit are working just fine as expected, but when I decrease R1 and R2 to less than 100 Ω the frequency doesn't increase more than about 200 kHz.

I tried reducing C, but got the same result and it seems somehow I can't get frequencies beyond 300 kHz. Is there any limitation for higher frequencies with the 555? Any suggestions?

Comment: What does the datasheet say for the specific brand and model you are using?

Comment: How precise you need the 1.7 MHz to be? What do you intend to do with it? Even if NE555 or CMOS 555 could go up to 1.7 MHz, it might be unusable for your purposes.

Comment: It doesn't need to be precise. Purpose is driving a piezoelectric element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [datasheet from TI](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ne555.pdf) for NE555 says near the top of page 9 that it best works from "from < 1mHz to 100 kHz". This is the suggested frequency. You shouldn't expect it to work reliably outside this range. Based on if you are using an original one from TI or a duplicate, it might have higher or lower range of operation.

I would say you let go of the idea to run a 555 at 1.7 MHz and use an RC ring oscillator using 7404 or 7400. There are many similar variants if you search "not gate RC oscillator". Use simulation to get rough values for R and C, then use a variable resistor to tune the frequency to your desired value.

Answer (score 3):

Use a different 555 timer... The TI [LMC555](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmc555.pdf) can run at up to 3MHz and should suit your application. Make sure you are soldering and not using a breadboard which has enough parasitic capacitance and inductance to be a problem for your target frequency. Solder or use a PCB if possible.

Comment: In this case, you have to be careful about the choice of the timing resistors and capacitor. If you choose a small resistance between pin 6 and 7, it might mean a high current going into pin 7 when discharging the capacitor. The internal BJT might get warm or limit the current, which might skew the timing.

Answer (score 1):

There are CMOS 555s that can struggle up to 1.7MHz. Eg. [TLC555](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc555.pdf).

However if you are intending on driving a typical thickness-mode piezo element for atomizing water at 1.7MHz, a 555 is not the best way to do it. See TDK's patent US 3,989,042 for some examples.